# Remove objects from array comparing with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array blackList where I store blacklisted business names, now I have a results array of objects with many business, I want to store in an array the business names which are not included in the blackListed array, what is the easier and most performant way to do this?

Is a nested loop really needed for this?

```
blackList = [ "Dominos Pizza", "Domino's Pizza", "McDonald's", "McDonalds",  "Telepizza", "Subway", "Burger King", "KFC", "Pans&Co", "Pans&Company" ,
        "Rodilla", "Rodilla Campamento", "Granier", "Llaollao" , "Taco Bell", "Wendy's", "Dunkin' Donuts", "Pizza Hut", "Papa John's Pizza", "Little Caesars",
        "Panera Bread", "Chipotle", "Papa Murphy's", "Hungry Howie", "Chipotle Mexican Grill", "Starbucks"],
        list = [ { name:'business 1' }, { name:'business 2' }, { name:'business 3' } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use `filter` and destructuring:

```js
const blackList = ["Dominos Pizza", "Domino's Pizza", "McDonald's", "McDonalds", "Telepizza", "Subway", "Burger King", "KFC", "Pans&Co", "Pans&Company",
  "Rodilla", "Rodilla Campamento", "Granier", "Llaollao", "Taco Bell", "Wendy's", "Dunkin' Donuts", "Pizza Hut", "Papa John's Pizza", "Little Caesars",
  "Panera Bread", "Chipotle", "Papa Murphy's", "Hungry Howie", "Chipotle Mexican Grill", "Starbucks"
];
const list = [{
  name: 'business 1'
}, {
  name: 'business 2'
}, {
  name: 'business 3'
}, {
  name: "Granier"
}];

const notOnBlacklist = list.filter(({ name }) => !blackList.includes(name));

console.log(notOnBlacklist);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
let blackList = 
  {"Dominos Pizza":1, "Domino's Pizza":1, "McDonald's":1, "McDonalds":1
  ,"Telepizza":1, "Subway":1, "Burger King":1, "KFC":1, "Pans&Co":1
  ,"Pans&Company":1, "Rodilla":1, "Rodilla Campamento":1, "Granier":1
  ,"Llaollao":1, "Taco Bell":1, "Wendy's":1, "Dunkin' Donuts":1, "Pizza Hut":1
  ,"Papa John's Pizza":1, "Little Caesars":1, "Panera Bread":1, "Chipotle":1
  ,"Papa Murphy's":1, "Hungry Howie":1, "Chipotle Mexican Grill":1
  ,"Starbucks":1 };
        
let list = [];

addBusiness("'business 1'");
addBusiness("Domino's Pizza");
addBusiness("'business 2'");
addBusiness("Hungry Howie");
addBusiness("'business 3'");

console.log(list);

function addBusiness (name) {
  if (blackList.hasOwnProperty(name)) return;
  list.push({'name':name});
}
```